# LWC linting error on <template> in new JS file

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I have just started learning LWC, and upon making a new component (helloWorld) on trailhead, when I try and upload to the org, I get the following error:

```
force-app/main/default/lwc/helloWorld/helloWorld.js  LWC1503: Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "jsx", "flow", "typescript". (1:0) (1:0)
```

I started this for the second time, as I got extremely confused with all the dev orgs, scratch orgs and the like. I deleted all and started fresh.

My linting has not changed whatsoever, and it used to work (Natural story of dev work).

I am not entirely sure where I would change this to fix the error, as all online issues are for web dev related stuff (I can't see how to implement the fixes with the SFDX structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please excuse me for being an idiot.

I pasted my .html markup in the .js file!

Sorry for wasting everyone's time who had a look at this.

Comment: Don't worry about it; we've all done something "silly" like this before. Maybe you'll end up helping someone else that did the same thing.